# How to write packages in go?

Tags: go

go is my first statically typed and compiled language so I am not sure about how to go about doing some things like writing packages...Should I write a package like...

```
package mypkg

import "fmt"

func mypkg {
    fmt.Println("mypackage")
}
```

and then import this into the main package....install it and then test if it works?

Or should I write `mypkg` like this...

```
package main

import "fmt"

func mypkg() {
    fmt.Println("mypackage")
}

func main() {
    mypkg()
}
```

Should I do it this way to make sure that I can call `go run mypkg` and see if it works, then delete the main function and rename the package and then work on the rest of the library?

Or did I miss the point entirely and I should do something else?

Comment: This question is a bit strange as the second version is **not** using a package and for the second part: Take a look at `go help run`: You simply **cannot** run a package. `go run` runs source code files (of which one must be a `package main` with a `func main()`. Take a look at how other projects are structured and read what `go {build,install,run}' does.

Comment: ok, the problem I was having with running main is that it was not finding my package files even though my paths are set and it told me it had searched the proper directories

Comment: To test use ‘go test‘ and write unit tests in *_test.go files. Read the docs on testing.

Comment: This is all explained in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) (notice it doesn't use `go run` for any examples)

Comment: @JimB I think `go run` is still valid since it does work. I had missed the part about naming packages via the `package` statement the same as the directory that holds them...but `go run` still does work...

Comment: @deltaskelta: `go run` can work with imports, otherwise it wouldn't be of much use. What it can't do is run a package or tests, and gets awkward when dealing with multiple files. Leave `go run` for quick tests of a file or two, and use `install` to build and install packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some basic steps to get you going if you want to use packages.

Create a folder called `mypkg` in the folder you're working in. In that folder create a `mypkg.go` file with the following code (note the capital letter in the function name. You need to do this so `main.go` can see it).

```
package mypkg

import "fmt"

func Mypkg {
    fmt.Println("mypackage")
}
```

Now install the package just by typing `go install` while you're still in your `mypkg` directory. This will create a linkable object file you can use.

Now go back to your starting directory and create `main.go` with the following code:

```
package main

import (
     "...(path to your mypkg folder)/mypkg"
     "fmt"
)

func main() {
    mypkg.Mypkg()
    //optional
    //fmt.Println("whatever")
}
```

Now run it by typing `go run main.go`. This will compile and run `main.go` that uses the previous `mypkg` package you created.